# Criando um chat-online com PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar um chat do tipo do facebook, gostaria de saber como ele funciona.

Nele conversamos e desconectamos e após reconectar é exibido o histórico de mensagens antigas em ordem perfeitamente, como fazer isso?

Comment: Sua pergunta já tem 3 votos para fechar, inclusive o meu. Ela está muito confusa e vaga. Li algumas vezes e não entendi direito o que é que você está perguntando. Você pode editá-la para deixá-la mais clara?

Comment: opa desculpe victor, cabei de editar ver se vc pode me ajudar agora, obrigado desde ja rs.

Comment: Tenha em mente que o Facebook possui um servidor que suporta uma quantidade massiva de usuários e de cadastros de registros... Se isso não for problema pra você, então comece a elaborar uma tabela que contenha `id_user_post_message`, `id_user_receive_message`, `message`, `date` de resto é lógica de programação.... Na hora da consulta do histórico basta fazer um `select` com `order by date`

Comment: @JuniorVieira Na verdade acho que a pergunta ficou ainda mais vaga do que antes. Antes pelo menos você dava uma ideia de como era o seu banco de dados, agora nem isso. :(

Comment: opa otima resposta, sim poderia usar a o order by date porem estaria listando as msg da pessoa e como listaria as minhas tambem em ordem correta ex: 
Carla disse: oi
Eu disse: oi

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você esteja esquecendo de manter uma coluna com o registro de data/hora das mensagens para poder ordenar por ela, outra opção é simplesmente ordenar pelo id da tabela, mas acho a primeira opção bem melhor. Controle pela session do usuário qual o horário da ultima consulta ao banco pra trazer só mensagens novas e reduzir seu consumo de banda.

Um bom conselho também seria você investir em alguma tecnologia de ajax reverso, ou mesmo um websocket simples (tem alguns exemplo prontos na web que dá pra customizar bem) assim seu sistema só faria as consultas quando realmente necessário e não de tempos em tempos. Eu já fiz um pequeno chat em javascript (bem básico, nem banco tinha) usando websockets e ficou bem legal.

Comment: obrigado querido otima resposta... + por exemplo eu fize-se por datahr listaria tudo blz, mais vamos supor usuario saiu, e volto como re-listar as msg em ordem novamente? por exemplo no facebook quando conectamos novamente ele lista as msg em ordem tudo certinho em ordem :p

Comment: @JuniorVieira ai você precisaria adicionar critérios de ORDER BY no seu SQL... você poderia colocar algo que você já tem pronto? Ficaria mais fácil para outras pessoas ajudarem.... Assim acredito também que sua pergunta pode ser reaberta por ficar mais objetiva.